# gorilla websocket NextWriter and WriteMessage() difference

Tags: go, sockets

i have function:

```
func write() {
    defer func() {
        serverConn.Close()
    }()
    for message := range msgChan {
        w, err := serverConn.NextWriter(websocket.TextMessage)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        bmessage, err := json.Marshal(message)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        _, err = w.Write(bmessage)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

And i got

```
panic: concurrent write to websocket connection
```

I'm wondering how is this possible? in ws writes only this function, which is running in 1 instance. and second question: what is the point of using NextWriter instead of just conn.WriteMessage()? Is it possible that with a large number of messages NextWriter accumulate and can try to write at the same time?

Comment: @CeriseLimón I didn't save it, but it has a line with w.Write(bmessage) and a line where go write() is called. that's it. of course, write only 1 instance, otherwise it would be a stupid question

Comment: @CeriseLimón no, not even a ping, nothing so obvious.
in theory, I can assume that there is a bug in the application that sometimes causes go write() to be called a second time, although this seems unlikely to me. but you want to say that the given function in one instance will never compete for ws and the reason is still in another?